# Beeline can't find private method "getKeytab"

Tags: hive, kerberos, beeline

I am trying to connect to Hive with Kerberos authentication using beeline. I have initialized a ticket with

`kinit -V --kdc-hostname=<HOSTNAME> -kt /etc/krb5.keytab <USER@REALM>`

and I can see it is active when I run `klist` but when I try to connect to Hive, I get the well known error message:

`SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]`

I changed the log4j level to debug, and found the following:

`DEBUG HiveAuthFactory: Cannot find private method "getKeytab" in class:org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation`

and after this, beeline is trying to use my unix username to authenticate, which is obviously failing. So I think the problem is that beeline doesn't find my keytab file.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is with beeline command.

Make sure you provide authentication parameter correctly and have double quotes around the connection string.

`beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://HOSTNAME:10000/default;principal=hive/hostname@Example.com"`

And also check your Kerberos principal if it has permission to access hive.

Comment: One important thing I missed, that it is working from windows and behaves this way from mac. My connection string is looking fine: `beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://<HOST>:<PORT>/default;principal=<service>/<FQDN>@<REALM>"`

Comment: Ok. check if your keytab has read permission.
Have you installed **krb5-libs** and **krb5-workstation**

Comment: Yes, the keytab has read permission. As I know, there are no krb5-lis and krb5-workstation on mac.